# Allow user to make post login call in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have laravel 5.2 app in which user is restricted to access `/login` if user is already logged in. Now we have implemented functionality of "**login in our app from other app (Not laravel)**". Now problem is, when **requesting app makes ajax call** to get login, laravel 5.2 returns perfect response if user is not logged in before request. But after login, if requesting app request again for login, **laravel app returns view of home page in response**. I want to customize it and make user logout before processing request for login. I have spend too much hours over internet and debugging. But everywhere people asking to restrict login page. But my requirement is to **allow request `/login` with post method and customize response**. If anyone knows answer, it will be appreciated.

Here is code of requesting app

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.78/my-app/login',
    data: {
        st_email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        st_password: 'myPass'
    }
}).success(function (response) {
    // getting view in response if user is already restrict
}).error(function () {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: you want to use the laravel app as an auth service for an other app?

Comment: @D.Hot, yes, I want to use laravel app as an auth service. Now please don't tell to use JWT. I can't go for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated you have this function:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

If you remove this if your app stop redirect you from /login. You can also just edit this function like that:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() and ! $request->isMethod('post')) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

this function redirect you only when you request isn't post method